# I got an error: ActivityNotFoundException

Tags: android, classnotfoundexception

I deleted `.TwoBase` and I replace it with `.Tutorial_1` but still, the app crashed when I clicked the first button (for `.Tutorial_1`) on the main menu and I still got this log from Android Monitor:

```
10-07 02:55:22.960 28283-28283/com.facebook.texttospeech E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                       Process: com.facebook.texttospeech, PID: 28283
                                                                       android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.facebook.texttospeech/com.android.howtodrawchibi.TwoBase}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
                                                                           at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1777)
                                                                           at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1501)
                                                                           at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3760)
                                                                           at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3721)
                                                                           at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4033)
                                                                           at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3999)
                                                                           at com.android.howtodrawchibi.MainMenu$1.onClick(MainMenu.java:36)
                                                                           at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4791)
                                                                           at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19884)
                                                                           at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5345)
                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:947)
                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:742)
```

Here's the `.MainMenu` that opens `.Tutorial_1`

```
public class MainMenu extends Activity {

Button button;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    addListenerOnButton();
}



public void addListenerOnButton() {

    final Context context = this;

    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

    button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {

            Intent intent = new Intent(context, Tutorial_1.class);
            startActivity(intent);

        }

    });


    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);

    button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {

            Intent intent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);

        }

    });


    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button4);

    button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {


            Intent intent = new Intent(context, About.class);
            startActivity(intent);

        }

    });

}
```

Here's the `.Tutorial_1` activity that I replaced to `.TwoBase`:

```
 public class Tutorial_1 extends Activity{

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.twobase_activity);
        }
}
```

Finally, here's the android manifest:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.android.howtodrawchibi">

<application
    android:hardwareAccelerated="false"
    android:largeHeap="true"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

    <activity
        android:name=".SplashScreen"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>


    <activity android:name=".MainMenu">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:name=".Tutorial_1" >
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:name=".About" >
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:name=".MainActivity">
    </activity


    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
</application>
```

Comment: clean and build your project

Comment: can you post the Tutorial_1 class?

Comment: I already posted it above, it's just short one because I'm testing it.

Comment: Did you clean and re-build your project as suggested above?

Comment: Yes, and it worked! Thanks for the suggestion, everyone.